# How to identify if a Windows Service is Hung?

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have developed a Windows Service which watches a directory and upon arrival of specific files, it sends out emails to users using SMTP.

The service has been in production for some time now. These days, occasionally the users complain that they have not recieved the mails for the daily workflow. The problem gets resolved after restarting the service.

The service log does not show any instance of error. My take is that the service gets Hung / unresponsive. Is there any way to identify when the service gets Hung or get notified about the same?  I mean, can this be handled as an exception ?

Also, what could be the possible reasons which may cause the service to hang?

**EDIT1**
Alternately, could the issue be caused due to File Watcher? Is it possible that the file watcher might have stopped running or become unresponsive? If so, are there any ways of simulating an unresponsive File watcher ?

**EDIT2**
The issue has been identified. The problem is with File Watcher. Apparently, the directory the watcher is looking over somehow becomes inaccessible, possibly due to network glitches. Now, if the directory is inaccessible, the FileWatcher gets confused and looses its way, thereby causing the service to become unresponsive.

Comment: What makes you think it hangs?

Comment: There is nothing on the logs. Had there been an exception, the exception handler would have caught the same and logged it. Also, the service is always in the started mode whenever the problem is reported. And works when restarted. This has lead to believe the service gets hung.

Comment: Then it might prove useful if you'd share some relevant code.

Comment: The issue has been identified. The problem is with File Watcher. Apparently, the directory the watcher is looking over somehow becomes inaccessible, possibly due to network glitches. Now, if the directory is inaccessible, the FileWatcher gets confused and looses its way, thereby causing the service to become unresponsive.
Thanks for looking into it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been identified. The problem is with File Watcher. Apparently, the directory the watcher is looking over somehow becomes inaccessible, possibly due to network glitches. Now, if the directory is inaccessible, the FileWatcher gets confused and looses its way, thereby causing the service to become unresponsive. Thanks for looking into it anyways.